# Questions regarding mailing Notice CP22A

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs

I received a notice (CP22A) similar to the image below: [image]

The only difference is that the Address in Red is written on my form.

---

**My Questions:**

1. I am confused where to I need to mail the form. PA or KA ?
2. Do I need to detach the lower bottom section where "Payment" is written and include it in the envelope they have sent me?
3. The envelope says "Please Print" on the left top. Is it asking me to mention my address?

Answer (score 2):

If you agree with the notice and just need to send the payment - you send it *to the address printed on the payment voucher*.

Attach the payment voucher to your payment (but don't staple).

Don't forget to write "1040" (or whatever else kind of tax return you submitted to which this notice is related), your SSN and the tax year in question on the check you're sending. I suggest mailing with certified mail. I'm not sure what "please print" you're referring, but usually on the left top is the place for the return address.

If you disagree with the notice or don't understand what's going on - seek a professional advice from a tax adviser (EA or CPA) licensed in your State.

Note that changes in your Federal tax return may trigger changes in your State tax return and you may need to file an amended return to your State.

Comment: "Please Print" on .gov forms typically means "write nicely, not that kaleidoscope you call cursive".

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answer. One more question,  I was wondering whether I need to place the voucher inside the envelope in such a way that the address (Kansas one) is visible from the small window that my envelope has.